# Why my paging bootstrap style does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I practice "Flask Web Development"blog article when paging links paging,bootstrap style does not work.But the other can be used.I was using macros import, hope that other places can be common this.Is it necessary to add at import time?                                                                                                                                                                                    .
somebody help me.

this is index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% import '_macros.html' as macros %}
{% block head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
            var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            /*background-color: #F0F0F0;*/
            position: relative;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
            background-position: top left, top left;
            background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
            background-size: auto, auto 100%;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            padding: 8em 4em 0 0;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: right;
            top: 0;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
        }

        .img {
            background-color: #235F2A;
            height: 23.6076%;
            width: 61.8%;
            margin-top: 14.5924%;
            margin-left: 19.1%;
            margin-right: 19.1%;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
        }

        .breadcrumb {
            margin-left: 25.28%;
            margin-top: 3%;
            width: 68.33%;
            background-color: #FFFF93;
        }

        .sketcho {
            width: 83.7%;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            opacity: 1;
            margin-left: 7.72%;
            margin-top: 8.5%;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            margin-left: 20%;
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .sketch {
            width: 83.7%;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            opacity: 1;
            margin-left: 7.72%;
            margin-top: 1%;
        }

        section {
            padding-left: 17px;
            padding-right: 17px;
        }

        .paging {
            margin-left: auto;
            text-align: center
        }

        .center {
            margin-top: 320px;
            height: 35px;
        }

        .row_button {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}


{% block page_content %}
<body id="top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for Article in Articles %}
    <div class="row sketch">
        <section id="one">
            <header class="major">
                {{ Article.head }}
            </header>
            <p>{{ Article.body }}</p>
            <ul class="actions">
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Learn More</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="row paging">
        {{ macros.pageination_widget(pageination, '.index') }}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

_macros.html

```
{% macro pageination_widget(pageination, endpoint) %}
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pageination">
            <li {% if not pageination.has_prev %} class="disabled" {% endif %}>
                <a href="{% if pageination.has_perv %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pageination.page - 1, **kwargs) }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">
                    &laquo;</a>
            </li>
            {% for page in pageination.iter_pages() %}
                {% if page %}
                    {% if page == pageination.page %}
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=page, **kwargs) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=page, **kwargs) }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#"></a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <li {% if not pageination.has_next %} class="disabled" {% endif %}>
                <a href=" {% if pageination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint,page=pageination.page + 1, **kwargs) }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">&raquo;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo on your class names.

Try `<ul class="pagination">` instead of `<ul class="pageination">`.

You can find the full docs for the classes to use here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination-default